# How can i re-create bing's webmaster verifiction DNS TXT record for an already verified domain?

Tags: bing, bing-webmaster-tools

Our website's Bing verification TXT record was accidentally deleted yet i see no way to create a new one for an already verified domain.
I'm afraid that as in 'google search console',  at some point the domain will be removed from bing's webmaster tools.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There was no option to re-verify and our domain Was removed after some time.
Only then we could verify it again but the statistics were lost.